# How to highlight the rows in google spreadsheet if the first column value is date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am very new to google spreadsheet and trying to use `conditional Formatting` to highlight the rows only if the first column value is Date.

- shared public google spreadsheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=1405439211

## My attempt

```
=not (isblank($A4))

// This is not working.
// But A4 is not fixed, on a new day if I insert some rows, $A4 might be $A5 and it may not work.
```

## Example google sheet

- this sheet has two columns `Date` and `Contents`.
- I want to highlight rows only when first value is date as shown below

```
Date     Contents

Dec 22   hello  --> highlight this row, since it has date on column Date
         hi      ---> don't hightlight this


Dec 21  This is another data and needs to be highlighted
        dont highlight me
        dont highlight me

Dec 20  highlight me

And so on.
```

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

```
=$A1<>""
```